# Implementing L-2 sensitivity - maybe using numba or JAX

Tags: python, performance, numpy, machine-learning, numba

I'm implementing L-2 sensitivity for a data set and a function f. From [this link on Differential Privacy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi5tbT4yKThAhUD4XMBHfq5CvcQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319620022-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1614771-p180940709&usg=AOvVaw3RqoeKqLz_v_yofpVp1TFO), the L-2 sensitivity is defined as follows:

[image]

I'm looking to incorporate this to make my gradient calculation in training an ML model differentially private.

In my context, `D` is a vector like this: `X = np.random.randn(100, 10)`

`D'` is defined to be the subset of `D` that has only a one row missing from `D`, for example `X_ = np.delete(X, 0, 0)`

`f` is the gradient vector (even though the definition says `f` is a real valued function). In my case `f(x)` evaluates to be `f(D)`like:

`grad_fx = (1/X.shape[0])*(((1/(1+np.exp(-(y * (X @ b.T))))) - 1) * (y * X)).sum(axis=0)`

where:

```
y = np.random.randn(100, 1)
b = np.random.randn(1, 10)
```

---

If my understanding of the definition is correct, I have to evaulate the 2-norm of `f(D) - f(D')` for all possible `D'` arrays and get the minimum.

Here's my implementation (I tried to accelerate with `numba.jit` and hence the usage of limited numpy functionality):

```
def l2_sensitivity(X, y, b):

  norms = []  
  for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    # making the neigboring dataset X'
    X_ = np.delete(X, i, 0)
    y_ = np.delete(X, i, 0)
    # calculate l2-norm of f(X)-f(X')
    grad_fx =(1/X.shape[0])*(((1/(1+np.exp(-(y * (X @ b.T))))) - 1) * (y * X)).sum(axis=0)
    grad_fx_ =(1/X_.shape[0])*(((1/(1+np.exp(-(y_ * (X_ @ b.T))))) - 1) * (y_ * X_)).sum(axis=0)
    grad_diff = grad_fx - grad_fx_
    norm = np.sqrt((grad_diff**2).sum())
    #norm = np.linalg.norm(compute_gradient(b, X, y) - compute_gradient(b,X_,y_))
    norms.append(norm)
  norms = np.array(norms)

  return norms.min()
```

Question:

The function call `l2_sensitivity(X, y, b)` takes a lot of time to run. How can I speed this up - -perhaps using numba or JAX?

Answer (score 0):

I just started studying this, but I don't think you need to do the full gradient calculation every time because the summations over D and D' differ by only the kth observation (row). I posted the derivation in this forum b/c I don't have rep for images, here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/206453/203228
Here is an example implementation

```
norms = []
B = np.random.rand(num_features) #choice of B is arbitrary
Y = labels #vector of classification labels of height n
X = observations #data matrix of shape nXnum_features
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    A = Y[i]*(np.dot(B.T,X[i])) 
    S = sigmoid(A) - 1 
    C = Y[i]*X[i] 
    norms.append(np.linalg.norm(S*C,ord=2))
sensitivity = max(norms) - min(norms)
```